# img:first-of-type selects all images

Tags: html, css, modernizr

I have two images in my page. I want the first one to show up when the user visits the website using a touch device or not supporting Javascript, by targeting them using Modernizr.

The menu button, on top of the page:

```
<img src="menubutton.png" alt="Menubutton">
```

The other image, which is just an image used in an article:

```
<img src="image.jpg" alt="Image">
```

In my CSS, I have this:

```
.no-touch img:first-of-type, .no-js img:first-of-type {
    display:none;
}
```

Now, this works almost just fine: the image is not shown on my laptop, but is shown on my iPad. But, the second image isn't also shown on my laptop. However, that second image is being shown on my iPad though. Also, if I target the first image by using an ID, it works the way I want it, but I can't use ID's unless it's really needed. What's happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first-of-type selector has *very* limited support. It will also be the first-of-type within its parent element, not within the whole document, this is likely to be the issue.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't know that it would select every first-of-type within its parent element. I replaced it with first-child, which seems to do the trick. Should have thought about that earlier. Thanks for pointing this out :).

Comment: @jgillich - only the latest generation of browsers support it as you can see, so with so with so many people stubbornly not upgrading, yes, it's limited!

Comment: @NickCardoso We might have a different definition of limited. IE8 doesn't support any of the newer HTML5 stuff, but this one even works on Android 2.1.